# wpf mouse hover grid row first element

Tags: wpf, grid, row

Is it possible to make when i hover over grid (template for items control) to change font color for first and last column in a row (this specific row which i am hovering)

What i want is "RowNumbering" object to change font color when we hover his "parent" row. To sort of highlite that row text.

Imagine it as a table:
where o is just a seat, and numbers are row numbers, when i hover over "o" i would like to change row number font color. I hope it's clear what i try, i did strip xaml to a minimum. Also would love to have this done over xaml if possible instead over code. Example bellow when i hover over "o" in second row.

1 | o | o | o | o | 1

**2** | o | o | o | o | **2**

3 | o | o | o | o | 3

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Seats}" Name="SeatsItems">
    <ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform  X="0" Y="0" />
    </ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid Name="ParentGrid" local:GridHelpers.RowCount="{Binding RowCount}" 
                  local:GridHelpers.ColumnCount="{Binding ColumnCount}" 
                  ShowGridLines="False" Background="#1C222E" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding RowEx}" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding ColumnEx}" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="{Binding ColSpan}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!--
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="60"/>
                </Trigger>
                -->
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Available">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#5D606D" />
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#5D606D" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Seat}">
            <Canvas Name="Canv" Width="30" Height="30" Margin="4" Background="Transparent" 
                    Tag="{Binding ID}">
                <Rectangle Name="RecTop" Canvas.Top="4" Canvas.Left="1" Width="28" 
                           Height="18" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" />
                <Rectangle Name="RecBot" Canvas.Top="23" Canvas.Left="1" Width="28" 
                           Height="7" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" />
                <!-- <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Column}" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  /> -->
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:RowNumbering}">
            <Canvas Width="30" Height="30" Margin="4" Background="Transparent">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}" Foreground="#5D606D" 
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="30" Height="20" 
                           Margin="0,5" />
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Screen}">
            <Canvas Height="5" Margin="0,0,0,33" Background="#EA1C47" ClipToBounds="False">
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong control type. WPF layout controls like Grid etc are useful when you want WPF to handle the layout of controls for you. In your case, however, the layout is already implicit in your data structures by virtue of the RowEx/ColumnEx properties. What you're trying to do is shoe-horn complex layout requirements into a layout control that's not really designed for it. You've already run into problems with this before, which has necessitated the use of that GridHelper. It's probably not going to get any better.

I write airline check-in systems for a living and find myself implementing systems very similar to what you're doing all the time. Experience has taught me that in cases like this, you're usually better off using a Canvas. It does require you to add much of the functionality that existing controls give you for free (e.g. row-specific behavior, which is something DataSet is better at handling), but it will give you complete flexibility over your layout and behaviors, and will also be much easier to unit-test.

To answer your question though, you could create a new class called `Row` with a transparent background that spans all of your columns. Bind that control's MouseEnter/MouseLeave events to update a local property in `Row`, and in those properties setters have them set/clear a highlight flag in the two `RowNumbering` instances that appear in that row. Alternatively each instance of `RowNumbering` could contain a property that points to its corresponding `Row` instance, and you could set a DataTrigger to trigger on that instead.

Comment: I was afraid something like this would come up. I was in doubt to create it like this or to draw everything manually on canvas. Looks like i choose wrong path. Also, performance when done my way is not really good. I will have to rethink, for now i have all that is really required. But i think i will have to rewrite it. Thank you for all your help